# ListBox topIndex doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I try to put the selectedIndex of a listbox at the top of the displayed list with this code :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sourceListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
    if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        int index = sourceListBox.FindString(textBox1.Text);
        if (index != -1 && sourceListBox.SelectedIndex != index)
        {
            sourceListBox.ClearSelected();
            sourceListBox.SetSelected(index, true);
            sourceListBox.TopIndex = sourceListBox.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sourceListBox.ClearSelected();
    }
    sourceListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
}
```

But the selected index is stuck at the bottom of the listbox :

[image]

And this is the only part of code that change the behavior of the listbox. **How can I fix that ?**

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other code that change the TopIndex in some way? For example in the SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: @Steve the event is not linked, I'm almost sure that no code change it

Comment: I think you have a logic problem here. If your current SelectedIndex is equal to the result of FindString, you never enter the code that set the TopIndex. In your image the first item that matches the textbox content is already the SelectedIndex so the code doesn't execute

Comment: This is a side-effect of changing the SelectionMode property.  Which is a "heavy" property, it requires destroying and re-creating the underlying native control.  That has side-effects, state gets lost when the window is destroyed that Winforms cannot or does not always restore.  Like losing track of top index.  Assigning it later is a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the call to `sourceListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;` is resetting the `TopIndex`. Setting the `TopIndex` *after* that call will work:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int topIndex = sourceListBox.TopIndex;

    sourceListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
    if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        int index = sourceListBox.FindString(textBox1.Text);
        if (index != -1 && sourceListBox.SelectedIndex != index)
        {
            sourceListBox.ClearSelected();
            sourceListBox.SetSelected(index, true);
            topIndex = sourceListBox.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sourceListBox.ClearSelected();
    }

    sourceListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
    sourceListBox.TopIndex = topIndex;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure _why_ that's the case though?

Comment: @petelids see this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189898/listbox-topindex-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment42866948_27189898)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the check against the surrent SelectedIndex and your code that sets the TopIndex will execute always, also if your current SelectedIndex is equal to the result of the FindString

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        .....
        int index = sourceListBox.FindString(textBox1.Text);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            sourceListBox.ClearSelected();
            sourceListBox.SetSelected(index, true);
            sourceListBox.TopIndex = sourceListBox.SelectedIndex;
        }
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
sourceListBox.TopIndex = sourceListBox.SelectedIndex;
```

to

```
sourceListBox.TopIndex = index;
```

Comment: Isn't this the *exact* same thing ?

Comment: No. Property SelectedIndex is influenced by SelectionMode.MultiExtended which is called at the end of the method.

Comment: Yes but it's influenced after the assignment, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

to a winforms listbox

```
SendMessage(listBox.Handle,LB_SETTOPINDEX, 0, 0);
```

will make the topmost item visible, guaranteed, WITHOUT
changing its selection state, which can be a nice touch when just starting an app and deserializing to load a listbox.